# How to return value from a function

Tags: c#, recursion, functional-programming, combinations

Hy there,

I am very new to programming, I have a code that can print all combination of size "k" from an array of size "n". but I want to use that information for further calculations. What should I do to store those combinations in separate array's? specifically, I want to store the temporary "Data" array.
i.e combination of {1,2,3} are {1},{2},{3},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3}
I want to store each combination in an array.
I hope my question is clear.

following is the code I want to modify.

```
// C# program to print all  
// combination of size r  
// in an array of size n 
using System;

class GFG
{

    /* arr[] ---> Input Array 
    data[] ---> Temporary array to  
                store current combination 
    start & end ---> Staring and Ending  
                     indexes in arr[] 
    index ---> Current index in data[] 
    r ---> Size of a combination 
           to be printed */
    static void combinationUtil(int[] arr, int n,
                                int r, int index,
                                int[] data, int i)
    {
        // Current combination is ready 
        // to be printed, print it 
        if (index == r)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < r; j++)
                Console.Write(data[j] + " ");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            return;
        }

        // When no more elements are  
        // there to put in data[] 
        if (i >= n)
            return;

        // current is included, put 
        // next at next location 
        data[index] = arr[i];
        combinationUtil(arr, n, r,
                        index + 1, data, i + 1);

        // current is excluded, replace 
        // it with next (Note that 
        // i+1 is passed, but index  
        // is not changed) 
        combinationUtil(arr, n, r, index,
                        data, i + 1);
    }

    // The main function that prints  
    // all combinations of size r 
    // in arr[] of size n. This  
    // function mainly uses combinationUtil() 
    static void printCombination(int[] arr,
                                 int n, int r)
    {
        // A temporary array to store 
        // all combination one by one 
        int[] data = new int[r];

        // Print all combination  
        // using temprary array 'data[]' 
        combinationUtil(arr, n, r, 0, data, 0);
    }

    // Driver Code 
    static public void Main()
    {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int r = 3;
        int n = arr.Length;
        printCombination(arr, n, r);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a small nitpick about the code - you actually don't need `n` since you have it in the function from `data.Length`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return value you can use this function syntax:
[type] [function name]
In this case it seems you want to return integer array so you can write:

```
int[] combinationUtil([members]){}
```

Something like this.
And you can collect return values outside of the function.

Comment: assume that i am very new, please be more specific. it says not all code path return a value

Comment: I understand that you want to get a group of arrays, The data type should be int[][], not int[].